# How to reset every variable in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am currently creating a quiz using PHP, HTML and mySQL for simply practice. However, I keep running into a problem where, the question displayed is different to the actual question linked to the answer. So where the user is correct, the answer is wrong.

Here is what I have for the question page:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    session_unset();

    $link = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx", "xxxx");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "There was an error connecting to the database!";
    }else{

        $qNo = rand(1,2);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questionID = '".$qNo."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $answer = $row[2];
        $question = $row[1]; 

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $_SESSION['question'] = $row[1];
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $answer;
            $_SESSION['userAnswer'] = $_POST['userAnswer'];
            header("Location: process.php");
        }

        }

?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Quiz v2</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Quiz!</h1>
    <div>
        <p><a><?php print_r($question);?></a></p>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="answer">Answer: </label><input name="userAnswer">
            <button name="submit">Answer</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I have for the process page:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    $link = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxxx","xxxx", "xxxx");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "There was an error connecting to the database!";
    }else{

            echo $_SESSION['userAnswer'];
            echo $_SESSION['answer'];
            echo $_SESSION['question'];

            if($_SESSION['userAnswer']==$_SESSION['answer']){

            }

        }

?>
```

Over here you can see the question displayed is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tFUl.jpg)

But this is what is actually being asked and compared:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7jrV.jpg)

Comment: `$answer = $row[2];
        $question = $row[1]; ` this looks fishy. Why do you get answer from your questions table?

Comment: You  might want to remove your credentials from the post, and change them on your server.

Comment: Please remove the MYSQL credentials and reset them.

Comment: `$answer = $row[2];  $question = $row[1]; ` you are returning question and answer from two different rows...

Comment: Yes, remove your credentials from public view.  Do you have an answers table or just a questions table?

Comment: @dmikester1 Is it legal for me to check for him?

Comment: Hah hah, I have no idea

Comment: If he does remove the creds, will they still be forever viewable in the revision history?

Comment: yes will be visible for ever and is not legal to use this credential without any consent from owner side

Comment: @AadilKhan Did you solve your issue? Was it the row[2] vs row[1]?

Comment: I only have a question table, do you suggest I make an answers table?  @dmikester1 Also thank you for the heads up about hiding my credentials. I am so clumsy at times! I'm such a noob at this.

Comment: make a separate table for the answers. It's a better choice to manage your script

Comment: Like Aynber and Ruddle said, I hope you have now changed your actual database credentials because everyone on the internet had access to them for about a day.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have made another table with answers, but I am still facing the same problem, any other solutions?